Getting Error Service Token is already used in track other service
I am trying to connect Wooffer in my backend to my code.
I have 2 environments.

Development

Live (Production)


in my production environment, the same code is working in production but whenever I try development code on my local device it's not working, here is my Code
const wooffer = require("beta-wooffer");

wooffer(process.env.woofferToken, process.env.woofferServiceToken);

I Added woofferToken and woofferServiceToken in my .env file
but I am getting an Error

I don't know How to fix that,
is there any way to solve the issue or I should delete the service and create new one ?
I tried many times to close and start again my developer server but it give the same error, Before deployment of production it was working fine.

You're facing connection problems with Wooffer, likely due to a configuration conflict. The woofferToken and woofferServiceToken you're using locally might already be in use elsewhere.
Troubleshooting Steps:
Navigate to your project -> service -> select the Development environment and navigate to the real-time page.

Check Real-time Usage:
If your service is using the credentials somewhere else, then it will show the prograss and you will get real-time monitoring of the application. In this case, you can check where you have used your configuration keys (i.e. woofferToken and woofferServiceToken) and act accordingly. You can also create new environment if required.
Verify Configuration Keys (if Real-time is inactive): If your real-time monitoring not showing any prograss or anything like that, that means you are using the Wooffer configuration credentials wrongly. In this case, go to the satup page. Copy the configuration keys (i.e. woofferToken and woofferServiceToken) and use those keys locally.

